# How to send data with Ajax with model.Form in Django and Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, modelform

Hey Guys, Could you help me to send post data to the form. Here what I have:
models:

```
class Test (models.Model):
    text    = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=300)
```

views:

```
def post_test(request):
    print 'aesewewewew'
    if request.is_ajax():
        print 'ajax'
        form = TestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('success')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('failed')
    else:
        print 'aaaaa'
```

templates:

```
<div id="post"></div>
<a href="/" onclick=click()>Post</a>
<script>
function click(){
    $.post("/post", {
        text: "eqweqeqeqweqw"
    },
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
)};
```

url:

```
(r'^post','test_propject.main.views.post_test'),
```

form:

```
class TestForm (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
```

It doesn't work for me. I can't find an error here. Could you give a link maybe to working code. Get request works fine. Maybe some way exist to make simple form, that has been created from Models, sends data via ajax, without reloading a page.

Thank you

Comment: I do not completely follow your code.  However, do you really want to check that the request is ajax?  Will it not be a post that occurs when your form is submitted?

Comment: Actually I just copy-paste it from another source. So if you have any ideas about view, you are welcome.

Comment: What happens when you make a post request? Does the request even reach the view? You could place a return HttpResponse('view called') at the start of the view to see if it gets called. If not you can try using '^post$'. Note the dollar sign. It really hard answering, since I have not idea where it is failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
def post_test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('success')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('failed')
```

I strongly suggest you study the tutorial [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/) before implementing the above ..

**Edit:**
Your urls.py should look something like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from test_project.main.views import post_test

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^post/$', post_test, name = 'post_test'),
)
```

And your templates:

```
<script>
function click(){
    $.post('{% url post_test %}', {
        text: "eqweqeqeqweqw"
    }
)};
</script>
```

Pls note that {% url post_test %}, doesn't work in external js files.

Comment: right now I have next:[28/Apr/2011 05:33:25] "GET /favicon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2330
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 281, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 321, in finish_response......error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I just noticed your urls.py. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

The main my problem was my  brain). I forgot to enclude:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('html').ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
            function getCookie(name) {
                var cookieValue = null;
                if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
                    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return cookieValue;
            }
            if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
            }

        });
    </script>
```